# How to enable Directory Listings in WebStorm's Built-in Webserver

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Is it possible to activate directory listings in WebStorm's/ PhpStorm's built-in webserver like in Apache (see screenshot below)?

[image: Directory Listing Apache]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this feature is not enabled for security reasons

Comment: Will there be an option to enable it in the future?

Comment: no, it's not planned (for the same reason - to prevent security vulnerabilities)